# Replacement for Windows camera app

Tags: gratis, windows-10, camera

I am looking for a replacement for the built-in Windows 10 camera app.

Like the built-in app, it must

- display camera live stream from cameras
- take screenshots of cameras

And it must have various additional features:

- ability to select a camera by name (the Windows app only switches to the next camera, which is super frustrating, if you have 7 like me)
- Ability to zoom to 100% (the Windows app can't zoom at all). I.e. if the camera receives a 4K picture and I have a FullHD monitor only, I want to see pixels 1:1, even if I need to pan in order to see the whole image

Other requirements:

- gratis